# Error when extending superclass to subclass in Java - polymorphism

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I'm currently tackling polymorphism on my java journey and I'm trying out these example codes in Eclipse. I just copied the codes but I'm really wondering why my codes wouldn't compile.

So I got three files: Example.java, Animals.java and Dog.java.

Example.java contains the main method:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal myDog = new Dog();
    }
}
```

Then I created two other classes for Animal and Dog as follows

Animal Class

```
public class Animal {

    public void makeNoise() {
    }

    public void eat(){
    }

    public void sleep() {   
    }

    public void roam() {

    }

}
```

Dog Class

```
public class Dog {

}
```

The way I understand it is that I can make Dog my subclass that extends the superclass Animal. But why wouldn't my codes compile?

Am I missing something in these codes?

Comment: Yes, you missed something. You never wrote the a `Dog`extends an `Animal` (<- hint in this sentence)

Comment: You're missing the `extends` part, you should read [a tutorial on inheritance in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Dog class doesnt extend animal class so this is invalid:

```
Animal myDog = new Dog();
```

you need to modify the class Dog in order to inherit the Animal Class

you achieve that doing:

```
public class Dog extends Animal{
```

Comment: Thanks :) .. But  I just got the codes from Headfirst Java Book when it discussed about polymorphism it gave the same example code without the "extends"?